# Cursor Pagination using ObjectID / Timestamp field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I sort and paginate records by a `last_message_id` field which takes an ObjectID (not timestamp), though both of them are the same if we deep dive.

The problem is some of the records may be ignored in pagination if we paginate using timestamp, because timestamps are not unique and they can be duplicate.

In my project there are two collections, "**Rooms**" and "**Messages**". Whenever a user sends a message, The associated room of the message will be updated with the `_id` of the message.
I do this because i want to show recently active rooms to users.

Is there a solution to the problem?

**Rooms:**

| _id | room_name | last_message_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | General | **612a8e6ab075cf9f2b8c6f9d** |
| y | Politics | **612a8e6ab075cf9f2b8c6f9e** |

**Messages:**

| _id | room_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 612a8e6ab075cf9f2b8c6f9e | y | ... |
| 612a8e6ab075cf9f2b8c6f9d | x | ... |

Comment: What problem, ordering on non-unique fields or ordering on objectid/timestamp as you said in the title?

Comment: @D.SM I solved my problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a compound index:
`['last_message_id', '_id']`
**The order of the fields must not be changed.**

We can also use a **timestamp** (`created_at`) rather than an **ObjectId** (`last_message_id`)

**Example:**

```js
// Pagination result: (limit 1)
[{_id: "613091804ae06dde2e507ff5", last_message_id: "612ff5e11d3130cc1fb1448e"}]

// to get more results:
// http://www.website.com/results?id=613091804ae06dde2e507ff5&last_message_id=612ff5e11d3130cc1fb1448e

// SudoQuery:
let id = req.query.id;
let last_message_id = req.query.last_message_id;
let query = {};

if (id && last_message_id) {
  query = {
    $or: [
      {
        last_message_id: {
          $lt: last_message_id 
        }
      },
      {
        last_message_id,
        _id: {
          $lt: id
        }
      }
    ]
  };
}

db.items.find(query).sort({last_message_id: -1, _id: -1}).limit(1);
```